# why is the app bar pushing the view pager down

Tags: android, android-layout

i tried to make the height of app bar as the sum of its children + the height of the status bar, but it ended up by pushing the view pager down. here is the image of the issue: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WLCc.jpg

here is the layouts:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and this is the layout of the view pager:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/contentContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

and this is the code for setting up the app bar height
:

```
    private fun setAppBarHeight() {
        val appBarLayout: AppBarLayout = findViewById(R.id.appbar)
        appBarLayout.layoutParams.height = getStatusBarHeight() + dpToPx(48 
    + 56)
    }

    private fun getStatusBarHeight(): Int {
        var result = 0
        val resourceId = resources.getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android")
        if (resourceId > 0) {
            result = resources.getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId)
        }
        return result
    }

    private fun dpToPx(dp: Int): Int {
        val density = resources
            .displayMetrics
            .density
        return Math.round(dp.toFloat() * density)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

move tablayout from inside of appbar layout and place below

```
<app bar
  <tooolbar
  </toolbar>
</app bar>
<tab layout/>
<view pager/> blah
```